# AngularJS ng-input cursor jumps during text entry

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular 1.2.25. When using the input field in a dynamically generated form, the cursor jumps to the end of the input field when any keys are pressed when in focus. This makes editing values very difficult. Is this an issue with the data binding? Is there a way to disable the binding updates when text is being entered?

```
<form name="editForm" ng-controller="applicationEdit">
    <td ng-repeat="(fieldName,fieldValue) in entry"
        ng-class="{'active' :  entry == selected }">
        <input ng-model="sections[key][$parent.$index][fieldName]"
            type="text" value="{{fieldValue}}" />
        <select ng-model="sections[key][$parent.$index]['ContactId']"
            ng-options="contact.Id as contact.Name for contact in contacts"
            ng-show="fieldName === 'Name'"
            ng-change="updateName(key,$parent.$index,entry)"></select>
    </td>
</form>
```

Comment: (Unrelated to the problem:) You have both `ng-model` and `value` in the `<input>`; this smells bad and may not work. The correct way is to initialize the model (something along the lines of `$scope.sections[key][$parent.$index][fieldName] = fieldValue`) and not to use the `value` attribute.

Comment: (About the problem:) Could it be that Angular is *redrawing* your input? Does the value of the input affect the form generation? Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: That was the issue. The value option was redrawing the input as you suspected.